# iptables string match does not work whe the --to option is < 52

Tags: command-line, networking, security, iptables, firewall

when I enter iptables rule which match string and the `--to` option is `>= 52`

example

```
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -m string --string anypattern --algo bm --to 100 -j DROP
```

The above works properly and block ip packets which contains "anypattern" string.

Now if I change the `--to` to a value `< 52` then it will not work

```
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -m string --string anypattern --algo bm --to 50 -j DROP
```

And the ip packets will not be blocked!

Am I missing something ? or this is an iptables issue ?

**Example:**

```
    linux:~$ sudo iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -m string --algo bm --string 7oula --to 52 -j DROP
    linux:~$ echo 7oulaaaaaaaaaaa | nc  212.227.247.109 80
    ^C  #<---- Blocked here
    linux:~$ sudo iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -m string --algo bm --string coula --to 51 -j DROP
    linux:~$ echo coulaaaaaaaaaaa | nc  212.227.247.109 80
    HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
    Server: nginx
    Date: Sun, 26 Jan 2020 15:35:55 GMT
    Content-Type: text/html
    Content-Length: 150
    Connection: close

    <html>
    <head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
    <body>
    <center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
    <hr><center>nginx</center>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: The `--to` switch tells the rule how much of the packet header to examine. I would gues that there's something in the 53rd pr following bytes that your rule wants to examine.

Comment: @waltinator, I added an example, you can test it with your PC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in kind that the offset is not relative to the start of the payload portion of the packet, but includes the header portion of the packet. Here is a tcpdump capture of one of the example packets, i.e.:

```
echo zoulaaaaaaaaaaa | nc  192.168.111.1 80
```

resulting in:

```
2020-01-26 11:51:10.606417 IP 192.168.111.122.43372 > 192.168.111.1.80: Flags [P.], seq 1:17, ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 3518227831 ecr 86824426], length 16: HTTP
    0x0000:  4500 0044 048c 4000 4006 d65b c0a8 6f7a  E..D..@.@..[..oz
                                           src-ip--
    0x0010:  c0a8 6f01 a96c 0050 8a87 b04c 40e2 7841  ..o..l.P...L@.xA
             dst-ip--  spt  dpt
    0x0020:  8018 01f6 ad1e 0000 0101 080a d1b3 e577  ...............w
    0x0030:  052c d5ea 7a6f 756c 6161 6161 6161 6161  .,..zoulaaaaaaaa
                       ^
                       |_ Offset 52
    0x0040:  6161 610a                                aaa.
```

By modifying your experimental iptables rules to this:

```
$ sudo iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -m string --algo bm --string boula --from 46 --to 51 -j DROP
$ sudo iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -m string --algo bm --string coula --from 47 --to 52 -j DROP
$ sudo iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -m string --algo bm --string doula --from 48 --to 53 -j DROP
$ sudo iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -m string --algo bm --string eoula --from 49 --to 54 -j DROP
$ sudo iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -m string --algo bm --string foula --from 50 --to 55 -j DROP
$ sudo iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -m string --algo bm --string goula --from 51 --to 56 -j DROP
$ sudo iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -m string --algo bm --string houla --from 52 --to 57 -j DROP
$ sudo iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -m string --algo bm --string ioula --from 53 --to 58 -j DROP
$ sudo iptables -v -x -n -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 23 packets, 1800 bytes)
 pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 11 packets, 1816 bytes)
pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   0        0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            STRING match  "ioula" ALGO name bm FROM 53 TO 58
   0        0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            STRING match  "houla" ALGO name bm FROM 52 TO 57
   0        0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            STRING match  "goula" ALGO name bm FROM 51 TO 56
   0        0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            STRING match  "foula" ALGO name bm FROM 50 TO 55
   0        0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            STRING match  "eoula" ALGO name bm FROM 49 TO 54
   0        0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            STRING match  "doula" ALGO name bm FROM 48 TO 53
   0        0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            STRING match  "coula" ALGO name bm FROM 47 TO 52
   0        0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            STRING match  "boula" ALGO name bm FROM 46 TO 51
```

We can try to gain more insight into the interpretation of the `to` and `from` parameters:

```
doug@rpi01:~ $ echo boulaaaaaaaaaaa | nc  192.168.111.1 80
Worked...
doug@rpi01:~ $ echo coulaaaaaaaaaaa | nc  192.168.111.1 80
^C  HTTP packet blocked
doug@rpi01:~ $ echo doulaaaaaaaaaaa | nc  192.168.111.1 80
^C HTTP packet blocked
doug@rpi01:~ $ echo eoulaaaaaaaaaaa | nc  192.168.111.1 80
^C HTTP packet blocked
doug@rpi01:~ $ echo foulaaaaaaaaaaa | nc  192.168.111.1 80
^C HTTP packet blocked
doug@rpi01:~ $ echo goulaaaaaaaaaaa | nc  192.168.111.1 80
^C HTTP packet blocked
doug@rpi01:~ $ echo houlaaaaaaaaaaa | nc  192.168.111.1 80
^C HTTP packet blocked
doug@rpi01:~ $ echo ioulaaaaaaaaaaa | nc  192.168.111.1 80
Worked...
doug@rpi01:~ $ sudo iptables -v -x -n -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 742 packets, 71452 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 509 packets, 59196 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            STRING match  "ioula" ALGO name bm FROM 53 TO 58
      11      748 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            STRING match  "houla" ALGO name bm FROM 52 TO 57
      11      748 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            STRING match  "goula" ALGO name bm FROM 51 TO 56
      11      748 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            STRING match  "foula" ALGO name bm FROM 50 TO 55
      11      748 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            STRING match  "eoula" ALGO name bm FROM 49 TO 54
      11      748 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            STRING match  "doula" ALGO name bm FROM 48 TO 53
      11      748 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            STRING match  "coula" ALGO name bm FROM 47 TO 52
       0        0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            STRING match  "boula" ALGO name bm FROM 46 TO 51
```

From the man pages:

```
   --from offset
          Set the offset from which it starts looking for any matching. If not passed, default is 0.

   --to offset
          Set the offset up to which should be scanned. That is, byte offset-1 (counting from 0) is the last one that is scanned.  If not passed, default is the packet size.
```

I assumed that `to` meant the last byte of the packet that would be checked. So, I would have expected only one of those packets to be blocked, not 6. However, and based on the man page description, then the results mostly make sense, when byte 52, the string start character, is included in the match window. However, this line:

```
  11      748 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            STRING match  "coula" ALGO name bm FROM 47 TO 52
```

Does not make sense, as byte 52 should have been excluded as a pattern start byte.

EDIT: I investigated. the example in my answer was from a pre 5.2 version kernel. This seems to have been fixed as of kernel 5.2-rc1, and that above line now doesn't block packets.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the issue now, In fact the match start from the IP payload and not from tcp payload.

Does adding -p tcp to the rule force the match to start from tcp payload?

Comment: I am not aware of a way to force the offset to be relative to the payload portion of the packet.